# Split na array to a multidimensional array alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, split, alphabetical

I have a PHP array returned to me in the following format:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [mainCatID] => 2
            [mainCatCode] => cat2
            [mainCatDesc] => Acupuncture
            [mainCatAddedDate] => 2016-10-12 10:22:49
            [mainCatStatus] => active
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [mainCatID] => 3
        [mainCatCode] => cat3
        [mainCatDesc] => Medical
        [mainCatAddedDate] => 2016-10-12 10:22:49
        [mainCatStatus] => active
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [mainCatID] => 4
        [mainCatCode] => cat4
        [mainCatDesc] => Aids & Hiv
        [mainCatAddedDate] => 2016-10-12 10:22:49
        [mainCatStatus] => active
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [mainCatID] => 1
        [mainCatCode] => cat1
        [mainCatDesc] => Brains
        [mainCatAddedDate] => 2016-10-12 10:22:49
        [mainCatStatus] => active
    )
```

What I would like to achieve is to split the array into different alphabetical "chunks" based on the [mainCatDesc] first alphabet. So the result is expected to be like the following:

**A**

Accupunture
Aids & Hiv

**B**

Brains

**M**

Medical

Thanks for the help in advance! Cheers!

- Edited *

so far I only have

```
$con = open_connection();
$allMainCatArray = getAllMainCat($con);
close_connection($con);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($allMainCatArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: you need to provide the code, what have you tried?

Comment: ahh code meaning?

Comment: what is this code?how is this code related to your question?

Comment: so far I only have a print_r() to output my returned array. I've attempted to use array chunk but the parameters the function needs doesn't seem to fit my needs

Comment: have you tried a simple loop? and some array pushing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this simple loop:

```
$newArray = [];//create a new array
foreach($array as $item) {
   $letter = $item['mainCatDesc'][0];//get the first letter


   if (!ctype_alpha($letter)) {//test if its letter
     $newArray['#'][] = $item['mainCatDesc'];

   } else if(count($newArray[$letter])) {//test if the letter is in the array
      $newArray[$letter][] = $item['mainCatDesc'];//save the value
   } else {
       $newArray[$letter] = [$item['mainCatDesc']];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code did not work just at is, but I managed to tweak it slightly to make it work! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would like to, however ask if it is possible to add in a condition that makes a new array for items that are does not start with alphabets? meaning to say that if it starts with a number or a symbol, it will create a new array under the # tag instead of A B C